# Automatically archive news with jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamically-generated

When I publish some news or updates on my website I want to display like the 5 newest ones and archive all the older ones automatically with creating sth like news/page2, news/page3 etc.

Since Im not using a cms Im writing the news by myself like this

```
<div class="news">            
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <div class="news_text">    
        content here...
    </div>
</div>
```

Are there any possibilities to automatically archive the news in dynamically created pages without me having to do that all the time I write sth new?

Comment: your page will become incredibly long.

Comment: @Daniel A.White Thats the reason why I want to create new pages instead of posting everything in one page.

Comment: The easiest way would be to store the news in a database and page the results. If all the html for all of the news items are in the source of the page, you could remove all but the first 5 using jQuery, but the data would still need to be sent over the wire and rendered before being removed, which is inefficient.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. I googled but didnt find any tutorials or sth on how to do this. Could you post some ideas or links on what to search for? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user2179266: I updated my question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible but you may need to let go of the 'pages'. Instead you can call the other news items in groups of 5 (or something like that) and display them on the same page.

You can do so using JavaScript (or jQuery if you like) with (or without) AJAX.

Since you don't have a CMS and don't plan on making one, I recommend the 'easy' jQuery approach.

Pseudo code would look like:

```
- Hide all news items 
- Show latest five items
- Make functionality to show next
  - Etc..
```

**Update**

A function in jQuery would look like:

```
toShow = 5;
i = 0;

//initial run
processNews();

//process button clicks
$('#nextItems').click(function() {
   if ((i + toShow) >= $('.news_text').length)
   {
       i = 0;
       processNews();
   }
   else
   {
       i = i + toShow;
       processNews();        
   }
});

$('#prevItems').click(function() {
   if ((i - toShow) < 0 )
   {
       i = $('.news_text').length - toShow;
       processNews();
   }
   else
   {
       i = i - toShow;
       processNews();        
   }
});

//show news items function
function processNews(){  
    $( "#display" ).empty();
    $('.news_text').hide();
    for (var j = i; j < i+toShow; j++) {
        var $new = $('.news_text:eq('+j+')');
        $('#display').add($('.news_text:eq('+j+')'));
        $new.fadeIn(400);
        // or other cool animations like:    $new.slideDown(300);
    }
};
```

Where `toShow` is the number of newsitems you want to display at the same time (currently I display 5).

You can then scroll through the news by using `divs` or `buttons` defined in my function by `nextItems` and `prevItems`.

So your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div id="news">
    <div id="display"></div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 1</h2> article one   </div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 2</h2> article two   </div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 3</h2> article three </div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 4</h2> article four  </div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 5</h2> article five  </div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 6</h2> article six   </div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 7</h2> article seven </div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 8</h2> article eight </div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 9</h2> article nine  </div>
    <div class="news_text"><h2>Headline 10</h2> article ten   </div>
    // etc....
</div>

<button id="prevItems">Show prev 5</button>
<button id="nextItems">Show next 5</button>
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amPzN/) of that implementation.

Note also, that you can alter the transition between the news items through `$new`.

Currently I have `$new.fadeIn(400);` but you can also do other cool things like `$new.slideDown(300);` which looks really cool if you let the height of your `<div id="news">` be `auto`. Play around with the times a bit as well. You can do some cool things :)

I hope this helps you out.

Have fun :)

**Update**

If you don't want all the news items to load in the beginning, but during process: you can use AJAX loading like I was talking about earlier.

For example changing the `processNews` function to this (untested so beware):

```
var page = 1;

//show news items function
function processNews(){  
    $( ".display" ).empty();
    for (var j = 0; j < toShow; j++) {
        $("#display").load("news/newsitems"+page+".html .news_text:eq("+j+")");
    }
};
```

Loads the first 5 newsitems found on page `newsitems1.html` which is in this case in a folder called `news` and must be accessible from your root folder.

You can then create multiple `html` files in this folder and access them by changing the variable `var page`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking about that too but as you said, all the other news would be lost. But it seems to be a good solution though. Im gonna try that and looking forward for your reply. Thank you!

Comment: @user2179266: I will make a function for this now. Hold on. :)

Comment: @user2179266: Please check my update. I hope this answers your question (please consider accepting it).

Comment: This is really awesome! Thank you very much Jean-Paul for your time and effort. I will definitely use that! :-) Although one thing left: I have to admit that I initially wanted that not all of the news will be stored in one page. So is it possible to load news out of another page when clicking the "nextItems" button? I could make that page containing 5 news by myself and leave the default page clean and empty with only 5 news to show.

Comment: I cant thank you enough Jean-Paul, one of the best answers given for me here yet. I learned a lot of your code. Wish you all the best :)

Comment: @user2179266: No problem. Thank you for the complement and good luck with your project!